# Migrating VM'S from KVM to Openstack

Tags: ubuntu, migration, openstack, kvm

I had KVM and Openstack installed on the same system.

I had cloned a VM in KVM and the instance is running , now I want the running VM to be moved to Openstack.  Does anyone here have any advice as to how I can accomplish this?

How do I move the VMs from KVM to Openstack?  Can you help me with the steps?  I would like each of my VM instances to become ACTIVE, and to have nova commands available.  (For example, nova list, nova delete, nova reboot)

Is this possible?  If so, what is the best way to do so?

Answer (score 3):

OpenStack isn't designed to add a running KVM instance that was started outside of OpenStack, because OpenStack makes assumptions about things like:

- How the VM is attached to the network
- Name of the libvirt domain
- Location of the files that contain the disks

The best thing to do would be to take a snapshot of your KVM instance, export it to an image file, and upload the image file to OpenStack.

Comment: Once you've uploaded the snapshot to glance, you'll want to launch a new instance from that snapshot, and when it's up and running, the migration will be complete.

Comment: Sorry for digging out an old post, I got the same problem. I assume new VM creation in OpenStack from this snapshot will means all the data will be saved? Is it possible to create this VM from the raw virtual disk of the old KVM one? The old one has cloud-init already configured, will the ssh-key also be saved?